# How can I change the first luncher of app?

Tags: android

When you open this application, the application icon appears in the center of the screen, after which the application environment opens and the movies appear.  I want to remove the interface when the application icon appears when I open it

Comment: It is not removable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the app **splash screen** (= the screen with the app's logo in the middle), however, you can modify the **splash screen** to your liking, for example by animating it.

See the official documentation here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen